# Text not contained with horizontal overflow property

Tags: html, css, overflow

Text overflows the div when trying to create a horizontal scroll. Hoping to get text to be contained, not overflow.

```css
.wrapper{
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap
}
.card{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `white-space: nowrap` property which alows the text to overflow the div... Use `display: flex` and then set the flex-direction to row...

```css
.wrapper{
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.card{
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

move `overflow-x: auto;` from `wrapper` to `card`

```css
  .wrapper {
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .card {
      overflow-x: auto;
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid grey;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="card">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat.
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat.
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat.
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
        veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        commodo consequat.
      </div>
    </div>
```